# Model flipped back to front

Tags: 3d-view

Hey its really hard to explain this but my model flipped some or something.
The front view is now the back of the gun i don't know how this happened i was just modeling and now its like this when i press 1 on the numpad. Anyone know how to fix? its hard getting the correct measurements back to front.

[image: huh?]
[image: ok]

Comment: Not sure how it happened. The model will "flip" if you scale it by a negative number - that could have happened by accident - it could also fix it - ( S (scale) > Y (axis) > -1 ). I suppose you could also rotate on Z by 180.

Comment: It's weird, when i do that the image switches back and it ends up still showing as backwards, is there anyway to edit the numpad 1 view angle?

Comment: Well, you can always make it do the "opposite" of any of it's default positions, just press Numpad9 afterwards (so Numpad 1 + 9), though it's not ideal. Is it possible you have another object "in front" or "behind" the main object that is "away" from the main object, but still showing up in ortho view?